# Maximum call stack size exceeded - Cypress

Tags: javascript, rest, cypress

I am trying to run a test, from first, it will get `x-auth-token` and I am storing that token within txt file, and then getting that token and storing in my `commands.js` file, like this:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("getAllNoteIDs", () => {
  let notes_ids = [];
  cy.readFile("cypress/user_data/token.txt").then((token) => {
    cy.log("Token is "+token)
  }) // Here I am getting correct token
  cy.request({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://practice.expandtesting.com/notes/api/notes",
    form: true,
    failOnStatusCode: false,
    timeout: 30000,
    headers: {
      accept: "application/json",
      "x-auth-token":
      cy.readFile("cypress/user_data/token.txt").then((token) => {
        cy.log(token)
      }),
    },
  }).then((response) => {
    cy.log(response)
    const responseBodyKeys = Cypress._.keys(response.body);
    cy.log(responseBodyKeys)
    cy.log(response.body['message'])
    let results = response.body.data;
    for (let i of results) {
      notes_ids.push(i.id);
    }
    cy.wrap(notes_ids);
  });
});
```

Whenever I ran this command, I am getting following error:
[image]
[image]

But, if I directly add token there, it runs fine. I don't want to follow that practice.
What's the solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x-auth-token type is `promise`

```js
"x-auth-token": 
  cy.readFile("cypress/user_data/token.txt").then((token) => {
    cy.log(token)
  })
```

change code

```js
cy.readFile("cypress/user_data/token.txt").then((token) => {
  cy.request({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://practice.expandtesting.com/notes/api/notes",
    form: true,
    failOnStatusCode: false,
    timeout: 30000,
    headers: {
      accept: "application/json",
      "x-auth-token": token // use token
    },
});
```

Comment: Awesome Man.. Hey Can you tell me, where I can learn about these basics?